# Is there any way to get ONLY the selects inputs from a form?

Tags: php, select, post, input

I need to get the name and value from many selects with POST, like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is I have other input types in this same form, like a checkbox, for example. I want to get in this foreach only the selects (I can't call by name cuz' each select have one name)

Comment: If you don't give an element a `name` attribute it is not submitted with the form. If you are using an element for just client side stuff (e.g. JS checkbox to enable/disable elements) and don't need it submitted then just don't give it a name. You can still access the element in JS if you give it an id.

Comment: Never rely on your client forms - I always can to send you every data, that I want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if all your parameters are in an array yes you can, for example, in your HTML you have something like :

```
<input type="text" name="data['first_name']" value="something"/>
<input type="text" name="data['last_name']" value="somethingElse"/>
```

in your PHP code, you can use a foreach like so :

```
foreach( $_POST['data'] as $data )
{
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm for my code. Exactly what I wanna do. Thank you and everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

The input element types are not sent to the server with your POST data.  Only the names and values are.

The only way to differentiate would be to send additional data, such as a list, or by naming the inputs differently.

Really though, you shouldn't be POSTing data that you don't care about anyway.  Save bandwidth, hide the elements that go nowhere with JavaScript on POST.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do that server side is to know exactly which inputs are selects and iterate through these.

```
$selects = array('select1', 'select2', ...);
foreach ($selects as $select) {
    $value = $_POST[$select];
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the select inside form you can do this

Your HTML:

```
<form>
<select name='selectName1'>
<option value='xx'>xx</option>
<option value='xx'>xx</option>
</select>
<select name='selectName2'>
<option value='xx'>xx</option>
<option value='xx'>xx</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Your PHP code

```
$arraySelect = array('selectName1', 'selectName2', ...);

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    if(in_array($key, $arraySelect))
       $$key = $value; //this will create a variable with the name you use, in this case $selectName1, $selectName2. And the option the user selected will be assigned.
```